# Extract some attributes in field to a new field in attribute table

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I want to transfer in the TESTE field(img) only cities(strings) to a new field but but with the same numeral representation. Ex: |1| |Guimarães|; |2| |Porto|.

[image: Teste Field]

@BERA and @Aaron I want that the final product looks like this

final product

[image]

Comment: Which ArcGIS version do you have?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your desired end product?

Comment: Is this a featureclass table or an ordinary table?

Answer (score 1):

Some python will help you combine the rows into a single value, you just then need to write that out to a new table.

[image: Input]

```py
import arcpy
tbl = r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\tbl"
mylist = list()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl,["stuff"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        val = row[0]
        if val.isnumeric():
            part1 = val
        else:
            combined = part1 + " " + val
            mylist.append(combined)

for x in mylist:
    print(x)
```

Generates a list that contains

```
1 Luton
2 Bedford
3 London
4 Manchester
5 Glasgow
```

This code assumes that you always have alternating number then name.